# Animation getting out of Sync

Tags: android, animation

So,

what i try to get is that 5 Views using a oval shape drawable, being animated. Its a circle getting scaled. The Animation itself is fine, looks fine when played on a single view. But when i try to stagger this animation on those 5 views, it take 1-2 cycled until it gets out of sync.

In on of my Fragment i do:

```
    final Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_indicator);
    final Animation animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_indicator);
    final Animation animation3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_indicator);
    final Animation animation4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_indicator);
    final Animation animation5 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_indicator);
    // 20 ms delay
    final int timeOffset = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.connection_indicator_time_offset);
    //
    animation1.setStartOffset(0);
    animation2.setStartOffset(timeOffset);
    animation3.setStartOffset(timeOffset * 2);
    animation4.setStartOffset(timeOffset * 3);
    animation5.setStartOffset(timeOffset * 4);
    //
    indicator1.startAnimation(animation1);
    indicator2.startAnimation(animation2);
    indicator3.startAnimation(animation3);
    indicator4.startAnimation(animation4);
    indicator5.startAnimation(animation5);
```

So i configured some delay in my values of 20ms which gets used to shift the initial time a bit for the visual effect i want to archive. The Animation takes 1000 milliseconds to play back:

```
<set
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:repeatCount="infinite">
    <alpha
        android:duration="@integer/connection_indicator_animation_speed"
        android:fromAlpha="0.7"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@integer/connection_indicator_animation_speed"
        android:fillBefore="true"
        android:fromXScale="0.5"
        android:fromYScale="0.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" />
</set>
```

So, question is how i can animate a couple of views and assure that the animation is in sync after a while ?

It seems all have to do the the setStartOffset call, when set to 0 all is good, but thats not what i want here.

thanks,
Kitesurfer

Comment: use Animators,  not Animations

Comment: Can you explain why that is better ?

Comment: because i just tested them and they work, animations are poor and shouldn't be used when you can use animators (v3+)

Comment: so, we had a testing today on an S3 Mini, and there it's not working.